# fitdist list issue

Tags: r, list, extract

I have a matrix

results[i]

with some data (distribution parameters):

```
list(structure(c(0.005, 0.004),
.Names = c("mean", "sd")))
```

for example.
I want to use fdist and I seed the distribution parameters with the values contained in results[i]:

```
params = fitdist( data, dist,method="mle",
                    start=list(mean =mapply("[", results[1], 1),
                               sd=mapply("[", results[1], 2)))
```

I got the following error:

```
the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
            with the error code 100
```

because the start list is:

```
structure(list(mean = structure(0.005, .Names = "mean"), 
sd = structure(0.004, .Names = "sd")), .Names = c("mean","sd"))
```

and it should be:

```
structure(list(mean = 0.005, sd = 0.004), .Names = c("mean","sd"))
```

The last output is obtained from:

```
params = fitdist( data, dist,method="mle",
                    start=list(mean=0.005,
                               sd=0.004))
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using "[[" instead of "[", the reason being that "[[" pulls the value at a list node, while "[" leaves the value still inside a list.

```
res =list(structure(c(0.005, 0.004),
          .Names = c("mean", "sd")))
list(mean =mapply("[[", res, 1),
                                sd=mapply("[[", res, 2))
$mean
[1] 0.005

$sd
[1] 0.004
```

(Although I would have used sapply.)

```
> list(mean =sapply( res,"[[", 1),
+                                sd=sapply(res,"[[", 2))
$mean
[1] 0.005

$sd
[1] 0.004

> dput( list(mean =sapply( res,"[[", 1),
+                                sd=sapply(res,"[[", 2)) )
structure(list(mean = 0.005, sd = 0.004), .Names = c("mean", 
"sd"))
```